# Can I use 0000 steel wool to remove streaks in my polyurethane finish?

Tags: furniture, polyurethane, finish

Can I use 0000 steel wool to make a better uniform finish?

Comment: Don't use _steel_ wool when working with water-borne "polyurethane" finishes.  You're talking about "sanding" a dried finish to make it more even?

Answer (score 4):

I would use a dual action orbital sander and wet/dry paper @1200 grit a very wet sponge to dampen the area dont press down let the sander float and as the streaks are cut out the residue will turn milky, keep wiping and moving this high grit with water will leave a mirror finish, I have used 800 & 1000 to remove larger imperfections but the 1200 works best in my opinion. (agree with JPHIL dont use steel wool)

Answer (score 1):

Once the urethane has dried, sanding will only fog up the surface. You could sand it to remove any large imperfections and then put on another coat. If you were getting streaks you may want to work in a slightly cooler area so it takes longer to dry and you have more time to work with it.